# How to target a specific table cell with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the #id of a particular table cell into a variable using jQuery but not having much luck. Can anyone offer some advice? I've made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/2rctvvh8/2/).

html

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />

<table id="myTable1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="1">
        cell 1
      </td>
      <td id="2">
        Get the id of this cell
      </td>
      <td id="3">
        cell 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var td = $(this).closest('table').attr('id'); //find table id
    alert(td);
  });
});
```

Comment: how should the code know which cell **you** want to target ?

Comment: I'm hoping you might help me with that.

Comment: Use `next` instead of `closest` like `$(this).next('table').attr('id');`

Comment: Which cell do you want to find? Always the second one?

Comment: No, it's actually a dynamic table with unique id's and I'm trying understand how to target them as  I want to populate them with data from an ajax call.

Comment: @JulianJ, I've posted one solution for you.

Comment: @JulianJ I've posted a solution to get the Id's for each cell. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Here's FIRST SOLUTION If you want to get all the id's from each cell. Hope it helps!**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button").click(function() {
    var ids = [];
    $("tr > td").each(function(index){
    ids.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    alert(ids);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />

<table id="myTable1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="1">
        cell 1
      </td>
      <td id="2">
        Get the id of this cell
      </td>
      <td id="3">
        cell 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here's a SECOND SOLUTION if you want to see the id's one by one.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("tr > td").each(function(index){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />

<table id="myTable1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="1">
        cell 1
      </td>
      <td id="2">
        Get the id of this cell
      </td>
      <td id="3">
        cell 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```